# How to handle different date formats in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am super new to Python.

I have a script that reads in multiple files. Each file has a different date format that I am able to handle using

```
temp_df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Invoice Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

I have a few issues that I can't seem to solve:

(1) One of my file has 2022-03-17 & 04/03/2022 with (YYYY-MM-DD) & (DD-MM-YYYY) respectively. So what I'm trying to do is apply different to_datetime() statement for different format and I could not figure out a way for the life of me. I tried to not specify a format but then it gets confused and messes up the format for rest of the dates too. Please note that **Data is only for March**.

[image: Data is only for March]

So what I thought to do was for example, if

```
pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Invoice Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')`
```

fails or gives an error, try

```
pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Invoice Date'],format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

(2) One of my file is missing a date for a transaction, I want to apply the first of current month for that record. I have tried the below but it applies the date to all records.

```
        if temp_df['Distributor Invoice Date'].isnull():
        temp_df['Distributor Invoice Date'] = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
```

(3) I want a new column called Month that uses the date from `temp_df['Invoice Date']`.

Comment: Let Pandas infer the datetime format. `pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Invoice Date'], dayfirst=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# 1. Date format
temp_df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Invoice Date'], dayfirst=True)

# 2. Fill missing transactions
d = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
temp_df['Distributor Invoice Date'] = temp_df['Distributor Invoice Date'].fillna(d)

# 3. New column
df['Month'] = temp_df['Invoice Date'].dt.month
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. Is there any way to format number 2 in '%m-%d-%Y'?

Comment: after `fillna()`, append `dt.strformat('%m-%d-%Y')`, it should work.